# Could not create the JVM: JVM log location

Tags: java, jvm, java-web-start, jvm-crash

I deploy an application via Java Webstart (using Oracle JDK/JRE 1.7 + Java FX 2).
It works fine for most users, however one of them sometimes (not always) gets this error when launching the application:

```
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occured. Program will exit.
```

Is there a way to get more information about what caused the problem (like a log)?
Any ideas of what the problem could be?

Comment: I think this is a hardware/RAM issue generally (especially since it happens sometimes).  Do some google searching and you will find a few people who have experienced this.  But it would be good to get more information on the user's machine.

Comment: I did google it, but noticed that most people who experienced a problem with memory had a specific error message, such as `Could not reserve enough space for object heap` for example. The PC is a Windows 7x64 with 8 Go of RAM and is not used in under intensive conditions. Do you know how I could specifically check that the amount of memory is sufficient before launching the app (I mean manually)?

Comment: well, I looked up Error: A Fatal Exeception... and the only things I found where memory errors (particularly from other stuff that uses Java).  editing run.bat/dat.bat were suggested as possible solutions?  Unfortunately due to the vague-ness of the error, its pretty hard to suggest a reliable solution, but here is what I found anyway: [link1](http://groups.google.com/group/akka-user/browse_thread/thread/bb0e26255984fc11?pli=1)    [link2](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/java-problem.68817/)    [link3](http://nest.array.ca/web/nest/forum/-/message_boards/message/234665)

Comment: @YoussefG. Thanks for the links. I actually tested with lower level of Xmx and it seems to work better. So you were probably right in thinking it was a memory issue.

Comment: @YoussefG.  Maybe you should collect your comments into a single answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied over from comments:
-I think this is a hardware/RAM issue generally (especially since it happens sometimes). Do some google searching and you will find a few people who have experienced this. But it would be good to get more information on the user's machine.
-well, I looked up Error: A Fatal Exeception... and the only things I found where memory errors (particularly from other stuff that uses Java). editing run.bat/dat.bat were suggested as possible solutions? Unfortunately due to the vague-ness of the error, its pretty hard to suggest a reliable solution, but here is what I found anyway:
 [link1](http://groups.google.com/group/akka-user/browse_thread/thread/bb0e26255984fc11?pli=1) [link2](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/java-problem.68817/) [link3](http://nest.array.ca/web/nest/forum/-/message_boards/message/234665)

Answer (score 1):

I had almost the same problem(I've got this error everytime) and fixed with changing in the **eclipse.ini**

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
```

to

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
900m
```

the 900 are the 
Xmx below